# how can newly joined members to blender sa correct serious mistakes they find

Tags: discussion

[Moving the 'center of the object' to the actual center...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44950/moving-the-center-of-the-object-to-the-actual-center?noredirect=1&lq=1)

this is not a duplicate. the answer provided (alt g) accurately answers a distinct question to what is asked in the purported "original question"

inaccurately marking this question as a duplicate of an unrelated question obfuscates the solution to what should be simple-to-solve situation.

please correct this.

Comment: I don't see how that question is not a duplicate since it specifically asks about origin positioning which is what linked question is about. Alt+G in the answer to dupe is addition and wasn't generally asked in the question itself. More than that Alt+G won't do anything if executed without repositioning origin first so it is not answer by itself

Comment: while i'm sure you make some good points...
the cold, hard facts are that one has the correct answer, the other does not.

Comment: *"the cold, hard facts"* nope, that can't be a fact since it's disputable and generally subjective. *"one has the correct answer, the other does not"* Both have correct answers which is Set Origin menu. Alt+G mentioned by you is not an answer to the original question "how to move origin of the object to its center", rather to the question "how to bring object to the center of the scene when its origin is in its center". In the marked duplicate mentioned above Alt+G is not an answer. It will not work without setting origin.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a duplicate to me? Both questions are asking how to move the origin to the center of the object (or perhaps the center of the object to the origin). The answer on the duplicate also mentions how to move the object to the center of the world, but as far as I can tell neither question asked for that originally anyway.

If you'd like to add your own answer or, perhaps ask/answer your own question, please do!